# How to specify Japanese fonts in CSS in a cross-browser way?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm having trouble using CSS to specify a Japanese font on some text in a way that Safari will accept. There's a widely-used Japanese font called **MS Gothic**. Here's the font's page [on the Microsoft site.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/ms-gothic)

I have it installed on my computer. (As would typical Japanese readers.)

I'm trying to specify the CSS to pick-up the installed font. Here's what my font-family declaration looks like:

```
font-family :  'MS Gothic', 'ＭＳ ゴシック' , 'MS ゴシック' , Msgothic, 'ヒラギノ明朝 ProN', sans-serif;
```

"ＭＳ ゴシック" is just the Japanese translation of "MS Gothic". And "ヒラギノ明朝 ProN" is a completely different font, that I added to catch when the CSS fallback stops. When I use the declaration above, it works in Chrome, and I get the font that I expect:

[image: Correct font in Chrome]

However, in Safari, it picks-up the wrong font - it actually renders the 5th one called "ヒラギノ明朝 ProN":

[image: Wrong font in Safari]

Here's the preview of the font installed on my machine:

[image: Font Preview]

... and here's the OS-level information:

[image: OS info]

How can I write the font name so that it works reliably across-browsers? I would expect the font name "MS Gothic" to get picked-up, because that's the filename. The font that actually gets rendered (ヒラギノ明朝 ProN) has a filename of ヒラギノ明朝 Pro.ttc:

[image: Hiragino font]

Note: Microsoft Word uses the Japanese translation of the font name to select it:

[image: MS Word using ＭＳ ゴシック]

Fiddle to test:

```css
#output {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-family :  'MS Gothic', 'ＭＳ ゴシック' , 'MS ゴシック' , Msgothic, 'ヒラギノ明朝 ProN', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  日本こんにちは
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the MS Gothic font, which is included with Windows, on a Mac. Have you acquired a separate license to use that font on a non-Windows device?

Comment: The font *is* installed on my machine though, and recognized by other applications. I don't recall exactly how it got installed - it may have been installed as part of Office. (It's also widely available as a free download, BTW.) Are you suggesting there's a separate font license file on the OS?

Comment: Just because someone makes the font available as a free download doesn't mean that it's legal for you to download and use it. I use Office on a MacBook, and (for recent versions, at least) the font is made available in Office using a font service, but it's not installed in MacOS.

Comment: My version of Office pretty old (2011). If I do `grep -Rl 'MS Gothic' /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011`, there are very many references to MS Gothic there. So maybe back then it was part of the install? In any case, it sounds like you're suggesting that my scenario (Mac user with MS Gothic) is not a typical scenario for a Japanese user?

Comment: I guess is the user has an older version of Office, then your scenario might be appropriate. But probably not for recent versions. Users can obtain separate licenses for the font to install on MacOS, but I don't know whether that would be common.

Comment: But can you think of a reason why Safari is not picking up the font in my case? In various articles I've seen, Japanes fonts are listed in CSS using latin characters - `MS Gothic`, double-byte equivalents mixed with katakana/hiragana/kanji - `ＭＳ ゴシック`, and even UTF-escaped character sequences `\6E38\30B4\30B7\30C3\30AF\4F53`. It's not clear to me exactly what the relationship between CSS font name is and the actual font on the user's device.

Comment: And just to be clear, when you say "users can obtain separate licenses for the font to install on MacOS," are you referring to a license "key" that activates the font in some way at the OS level, or just that they purchase the rights to use it?

Comment: Purchase the rights to use it. On the page on the Microsoft site you mentioned in your question, there's a section on licensing, with a link to where one can go to obtain a separate license to the MS Gothic font.

Comment: But how do I know if it's already licensed? For example, MS Office includes and installs the font Calibri. (This is well known - there are court cases where it's been proven that documents were forged because they used Calibri, which wasn't available until MS Office started shipping it.) But the license file in Office doesn't mention Calibri - or any fonts - by name. So how does a user who has Calibri show that they are licensed to use Calibri?

Comment: If the font was installed with an Office install, then the user has a valid license to use it. I was only observing that it appears the most recent versions of Office on the Mac don't install any fonts: I have Office with a Microsoft 365 subscription on a MacBook, and Calibri and MS Gothic are available in the Office apps, but are not installed on the MacBook.